# Chrome debugger looses blue highlight while code walkthrough

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

i faced this issue recently. Actually i have to debug a JS file with 40K - 50K lines of code, while stepping through the codes the blue highlight ( which denotes that the current control is at that line) disappear whereas the control is still stopped at that line. Have anyone faced this issue? What is the solution for the above issue?